# Why the difference in metal between 銀行 and お金?

Tags: etymology

Money seems to be about gold but banks about silver. Is this due to an evolution of the status of the valuable metals themselves? Is it a complicated (e.g. ateji) etymology?

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, the native word [金（かね）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/43677/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AD/) in お金 only means *metal* and **not** *gold*. You may have mixed it up with the Sino-Japanese [金（きん）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58723/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8D%E3%82%93/) that means *gold* (it also means *metal* as a morpheme, but not for a standalone word). The native word for *gold* is [こがね](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/76300/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AD/) "yellow-metal". Thus money is called お金 just because coins are made of metals. No mystery :)

On the other hand, 銀行 is [a relatively newly imported word](http://yain.jp/i/%E9%8A%80%E8%A1%8C) from Chinese originally means 銀 "silver" + 行 "guild". What was traditionally the standard money in Japan is [a quite debatable topic](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E8%B2%A8%E5%B9%A3%E5%8F%B2) (gold, silver, copper, or rice??), but China has a long tradition of silver standard system, so that's why silver is the synonym of money for them.

Comment: Interesting, I'm finding explanations that 銀行 is a wasei-kango.

Comment: @droooze FYI I've found old [Chartered Bank](http://www.antiquemoney.com/chartered-bank-of-india-australia-china-bank-notes/value-of-chartered-bank-of-india-australia-china-5-bank-note-2nd-january-1865/) and [HSBC](http://www.antiquemoney.com/the-hong-kong-shanghai-banking-corporation/value-of-hong-kong-shanghai-25-bank-note-1865-1867/) banknotes issued on 1865, prior to Japanese Meiji restroration, have 銀行 printed on their face.

Comment: Ahhh okay, as https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%8A%80%E8%A1%8C suggests and from what I could find the first appearance of the term does indeed look like its from the name of HSBC. I guess I didn't find the explanation convincing at first because China had bank-type establishments since the Song Dynasty called 錢莊, and 銀行 originally referred to a Silversmith-type profession in Classical Chinese.

Comment: At some point it was decided to use 金 for かね, not 銀, etc.Why?

Comment: @MathieuBouville I'm not sure I clearly understand your comment, but do you mean おかね should have adopted another kanji than the word かね because of the meaning difference?

Comment: @droooze Thank you for your input. That info adds to fun when you know that the earliest form of banking in England was assumed by goldsmiths.

Comment: @broccoliforest And when you consider that the English word _bank_ is etymologically the same word as _bench_ (referring originally to some kind of table-like structure)…

Comment: See also [the 金【かね】 entry at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%87%91#Etymology_2).  This term _kane_ historically had four kanji spellings, 金・鉄・銀・銅, pointing to the importance of these four metals.